# Count unique values and return results in another column

Tags: excel, vba, count, unique-values

I have values in column B (green, blue, white....) and I want to count them and the result must appear in column A in the following format (green01, green02, green03...., blue01, blue02, blue03, blue04...., white01, white 02...).

The result must look like in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whcPs.png)

I have searched the net for a macro, but I didn't find one to fit my needs.

THX

Comment: You can use COUNTIF for this.

Comment: Must the font of each color reflect the name, like in your picture, or that coloring is only for making the picture more elocvent...? Are the colors in B;B sorted somehow?

Comment: @FaneDuru The colour does not matter. I put it there only to show the differences.

Comment: Test my code, please. It colors also the font. But you can comment/delete the last line of the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No VBA needed, in `A1`:

```
=B1&TEXT(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1),"00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testCountSortColors()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, c As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  sh.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Sort key1:=sh.Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

  For i = 2 To lastRow
    If sh.Range("B" & i).value <> sh.Range("B" & i - 1).value Then
        c = 1
    Else
        c = c + 1
    End If
    sh.Range("A" & i).value = sh.Range("B" & i).value & Format(c, "00")
    sh.Range("A" & i).Font.Color = sh.Range("B" & i).Font.Color
  Next
End Sub
```

I thought you maybe have column headers...

Answer (score 0):

### A Unique Count

Adjust the values in the constants section.

```
Option Explicit

Sub countUnique()

    Const SourceColumn As Variant = 2   ' e.g. 2 or "B"
    Const TargetColumn As Variant = 1   ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim Source As Variant, Target As Variant
    Dim i As Long, UB As Long
    Dim CurrString As String

    Set rng = Columns(SourceColumn).Find(What:="*", _
      LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitProcedure
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then GoTo exitProcedure
    Source = Range(Cells(FirstRow, SourceColumn), rng)
    Set rng = Nothing

    UB = UBound(Source)
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UB
        If Source(i, 1) <> "" Then
            dict(Source(i, 1)) = dict(Source(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Target(1 To UB, 1 To 1)
    For i = UB To 1 Step -1
        CurrString = Source(i, 1)
        If CurrString <> "" Then
            Target(i, 1) = CurrString & Format(dict(CurrString), "00")
            dict(CurrString) = dict(CurrString) - 1
        End If
    Next i

    With Cells(FirstRow, TargetColumn)
        .Resize(Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(UB) = Target
    End With

    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully."

exitProcedure:

End Sub
```